# How to pass a file stream as an argument to a Rcpp-function?

Tags: stream, pass-by-reference, rcpp

I am new to Rcpp. My problem: I want to have a function (`writeToFile`) that writes to a file on my hard drive.

This function shall be called several times within a second function (`foo`). Thus I want to open the stream only once, write to the file and close the stream.

What I've already learned: In C++ streams need to be passed by reference.

My code, however, where the argument `myfile` is passed by reference  does not compile:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void writeToFile (ostream& myfile, string text) {
  myfile << text << "\n";
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void foo (string text, int n,  string file = "example.txt") {
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open(file.c_str());
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    writeToFile(myfile, text);
  }
}
```

I get the error message:

```
    std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ostream(std::basic_ostream<<_CharT, _Traits>&&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]' is protected within this context.
```

Any tips what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your function `foo()` has types that can be mapped to R.  But `writeToFile()` does not.  So you need to 'hide it' and provide an interface -- like foo does.  So maybe just remove `// [[Rcpp::export]]` in front of it?

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot.